# Revert default style on load

Tags: magento2.2

Sure I am missing some point.
I change the any style in **style.css**

> - pub\static\frontend\author\theme\en_US\css

And when I refresh Magento 2 site, all styles are revert back to default values.

how can I change the **color and font-family?**

Comment: Dont change the styles directly in pub/static/frontend/. You need to change the styles under your theme like app/design/author/theme/web/css/source

Comment: check my comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you add/edit style.css is the wrong path. it's cache folder where Magento stored all static files after process on actual files to create the cache for fast load

follow below steps for change into style

1) you need to create a new theme takes reference from [here](https://github.com/hitesh-srtpl/magento225-demo/tree/master/app/design/frontend/Srtpl/default)

2) copy file which you want to change at this path app/design/frontend/Customtheme/default/web/css

3) run this command **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

Comment: I am using predefine theme, what my task is just to change the colors and font-family.
Even I check this path and it does not have all the labels which help me to change the colors.
'app\design\frontend\author\theme\web\css\source'

Comment: as Magento standard, you have to define your custom theme if you want to change into any default theme css files.

Comment: I am using this theme [link](https://themeforest.net/item/pedona-responsive-magento-theme/22451210), task is, just to change colors from orange - blue

Comment: Ok then go to your pedona theme find style.css or same like other css where you can add style under web/css and add/update css there.

Comment: Here is the path: `pub/static/frontend/pedona/pedona_page5/en_US/css/style.css`

but again, change the color from orange to blue and once I hit refresh the style.css also revert the color from blue to orange ( default color )

Comment: seems, there is some processor ( I think, LESS ), when ever page refresh it compile .less file and compile it into style.css